# Keyboard Event doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, events, keyboard

I recently decided to add keyboard events for my scrollbar. I add an event listener on stage and a handler for handling the triggered event. I put only trace inside the handler. The code works on the first scene but it doesn't on the second and thereafter. Tried to add the listener again on this scene with no result. Can someone tell me what is going on?

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown);

function handleKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
var key:uint = e.keyCode;
switch(key){
    case Keyboard.UP:
        trace("UP");
    break;
    case Keyboard.DOWN:
        trace("DOWN");
    break;
    default:
        trace("Wrong key");
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: It may be due to removed event listener. Check where you removing this listener, and make shure it is not between scenes.

Comment: I didn't remove the listener. It works on "start" scene. When I go on the next scene (named "act1") it doens't work. I go to next scene ("act2") and then return to "act1" scene and then it works. I didnt even write code for removing the listener and when I trace it, it's true on all scenes.

Comment: try adding/initializing input handling not on start of the scene, but on start of program, creating dedicated class for this purpose